# Installing RabbitMQ & Erlang without root

Tags: rpm, rabbitmq, erlang

So this client has a lot of internal regulations and has issues getting root access. 
While RabbitMQ has a "generix Linux" install that doesn't require root access, it still relies on ErLang 
Is there a "generic" or non-root intall or Erlang ?
It would be for a Centos/RHEL type Linux
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welp, if you have access to gcc/llvm I'm assuming you could compile it; download & extract a tar.gz from erlangs webpage then hopefully run the install script provided. You might have troubles binding rabbitmq to erlang though.